# how can i change-hide controller name from url in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project using MVC-5. when i run my application, I'm getting this URL: `http://192.169.235.120/home/home` , but i want it to be like this: `http://192.169.235.120/home`

so is this possible in MVC-5

Comment: you have a home folder inside a home folder?

Comment: you made a view called home , inside the home controller?

Comment: @Syfer No. we don't have home folder inside a home folder

Comment: @Ahmad Yes. we made a view called home

Comment: yeah that's why you're getting this @ashish

Comment: @Ahmad then what we can do

Comment: @Ahmad we don't want show the Controller name in URL

Comment: check my answer @ashish

Comment: @Ahmad we don't want show the controller name for all the url

Comment: add your `HomeController` and your `View` in the question please

Comment: this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799273/how-to-remove-controller-name-from-url-in-mvc-project/57799331#57799331

Answer (score 3):

You could either change the route as stated in Ahmad's answer or rename your action to Index. MVC automatically routes to `http://{host}/ControllerName/ActionName`; in your case this seems to be the action "Home" on controller "Home". Rename your action "Home" to "Index" and you'll be able to acces `http://{host}/Home`, don't forget to rename your view as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should map new route in the `Global.asax` or `RouteConfig.cs` if you're using **`MVC 4`**, (add it before the default one), for example:

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecificRoute", "{action}/{id}", new {controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

// default route
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```

**Hope this is helpful :)**