# How to remove controller name from URL in MVC project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, redirect, controller

I have a URL like below and I need to remove the controller name (myController). I've use several fixes but none fixed the issue. Please help me guys..

http://foldername.example.com/foldername/myController/my-page

'example.com' is the domain and all the files related to the site is inside 'foldername' folder. 'my-page' is the view name

In the end I need the above URL to be like below.

http://example.com/my-page

Thank in advance guys..!!

Comment: remove/create new maproute located in your global.asax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Removing controller name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

You could try inverting the routes definition by placing the more specialized route first. Also you probably didn't want to hardcode the action name as action but rather use the `{action}` placeholder:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Special",
        url: "{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "LandingIndex" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
   }
}
```

Follow the below links :

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url)

[Link 2](https://forums.asp.net/t/2094374.aspx?hide%20controller%20name%20ActionMethod%20in%20Url%20)

[Link 3](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1090247/Remove-controller-name-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Enable attribute routing by adding following line before route.MapRoute in RouteConfig.cs file

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then add the Route Attribute to each action with the route name, like:

```
[Route("MyAction")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Routing in the `global.asax`

```
routes.MapRoute("MyAction", "{action}/{id}", new {controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

and in controller

```
[Route("MyAction")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
 ...
 }
```

add following to `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should map new route in the global.asax (add it before the default one), for example:

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecificRoute", "{action}/{id}", new {controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```